# Is there a good (PHP) frontend for editing PO files

Tags: php, internationalization, po

We're working with a lot of non-professional translators: i.e. people in our overseas branches. I want to use PO files, but it's problematic getting 30+ unskilled people to edit them. I'd like a web front to edit these - ideally PHP as that's what everything else is in. Is there a mature web frontend that can be trusted to be up to date in five years time?

Comment: Not 100% sure exactly, but this might be something you could look into if I'm understanding right.. http://www.poedit.net/

Comment: Best to have a look at the [few offerings on the web](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gettext+web+interface).

Comment: @Zack: I think the OP wants it web-based, that is off-line.

Comment: Its a _very_ simple file format. Its not difficult to create an own one.

Comment: Up to date in five years? Where can I send the service contract to?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the translation application to be php just because the original app to be translated is written in php (although it could be easier to install and manage since you're familiar with it).

You could use [Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org/) (uses Python and Django framework).  It does exactly what you need: a web interface for editing .po files. See for yourself an [example for an Abiword translation](http://pootle.locamotion.org/ach/abiword/abiword.po/translate/). Just run your own copy as an intranet application.

> Pootle is a user-friendly web portal
>   that makes the translation process so
>   much simpler. It allows online
>   translation, work assignment, gives
>   statistics and allows easy volunteer
>   contribution.